# How to search details employees data by using employee id using spring boot and angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project. In that I want to search details by using employee ID .
I got result in postman when I get empData by using id.
But I didn't work in angular. I kept search bar to get details but it not get the employee details when I enter id in searchbar.

Can anyone please solve this solution.I will give the basic code

This is my spring boot controller class of employee code

```
@GetMapping("/findemp/{id}")
    public EmployeeEntity findEmployee(@PathVariable int id){
        
        return empRepository.findByid(id);
    }
```

serarchComponent.ts

```
export class SearchDeleteComponent implements OnInit {

  emps:Observable<Emp[]>;
  emps1:any;
  id:number;

    constructor(public empService: EmpRegistrationService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.empService.getEmployees().subscribe(data => {
        this.emps = data;
      });
    }

    delteUser(id:number){
      this.empService.deleteEmp(id).subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.ngOnInit();
        },
        error => console.log(error));
    }
     public findEmpById(id: number){
      //  let resp = this.empService.getEmpById(this.id);
      //  resp.subscribe((data)=>this.emps=data);
 }
}
```

search component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <br/>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10 col-lg-8">
      <form class="card card-sm">
        <div class="card-body row no-gutters align-items-center">
          <div class="col-auto">
            <i class="fas fa-search h4 text-body"></i>
          </div>
          <!--end of col-->
          <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" type="search"
                   placeholder="Search topics or keywords">
          </div>
          <!--end of col-->
          <div class="col-auto">
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" (click)="findEmpById(id)">Search</button>
          </div>
          <!--end of col-->
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--end of col-->
  </div>
</div>
```

In "emp-registration-service.ts" I wrote url of springboot

```
public getEmpById(id: number): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/findemp/"+id)

  }
```

I want get data when I search by id

Comment: Do you have any errors in browser console?

Comment: No It not showing anything but internally it showing  i.e which we give id number in search the id value get undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controller of Searching function

```
@GetMapping("/findemp/{id}")
public EmployeeEntity findEmployee(@PathVariable int id){
    
    return empRepository.findById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this annotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` , Your method should now be something like

```
@GetMapping("/findemp/{id}")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public EmployeeEntity findEmployee(@PathVariable int id){

return empRepository.findById(id);
}
```

The reason is that your angular app is running on a different domain.For security reasons, browsers prohibit AJAX calls to resources residing outside the current origin. That's why it works on postman and not on browser

Comment: so what I have to change the code can u please explain@Emmanuel Ogoma